# Run nodejs npm package from notepad++ console

Tags: node.js, notepad++, npm, nppexec

I'm trying to run some nodejs apps in *Notepad++*. I installed *NppExec* and `node` works just fine in the console, but npm packages don't run even though I installed them with the `-g` flag. My current workaround is to call `cmd` from the console and then running the app like:

```
// `cmd` inside Notepad++ console

C:\>lessc "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" > "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).css"
```

How can I run it straight from the *Notepad++* console without having to go into `cmd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly this looks like a bug in NppExec, where it cannot run .cmd files from PATH.

A workaround would be to run:

```
where lessc
```

You'll get the path to the command like: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd`
Use that path inside NppExec console.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" > "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).css"
```

However I'd stick to the solution you already found, looks far more better to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not really a solution but worth an upvote xD

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old but still appears high up google results.
To run .bat or .cmd you need to add the extension.

```
npp.cmd start
```

From Docs [Npp_Exec Manual](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~aedv/Notepad++Portable/App/Notepad++_ansi/plugins/doc/NppExec_Manual.txt):

> The same approach can be used to execute .bat and .cmd files - but the file extension (.bat or .cmd) can not be omitted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd /c cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & node $(FILE_NAME) & pause
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.